# xamarin complex numbers electromagnetics

Tags: xamarin

I have this assignment to do
Download an app called any.do
It's a to-do list
Do a project that's a copy of this.
Not all features are needed but only main ones like

Creating Todo list
Marking as complete
Deleting tasks
Editing tasks
Time reminders

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: making a xamarin app

Comment: Download an app called any.do
It's a to-do list
Do a project that's a copy of this.
Not all features are needed but only main ones like

Creating Todo list..
Marking as complete..
Deleting tasks..
Editing tasks..
Time reminders..

Comment: @ Dennis Schroer please help if you can

Comment: I'd love to help, but "making a xamarin app" is not a question. I'm afraid that I still have no clue what your question is